# Flexbox "align-items : center" shrinks a child's max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox div `container` with `align-items: center`, with three childs. One of them has `max-width: 200px` (in the code, `second-ch`), and it's also a flex with two childs distributed with `justify-content: space-between`, but `second-ch` is not following its `max-width`. If I remove `align-items: center` from `container`, `second-ch` takes again the width desired but the remaining elements are not in the center anymore. How can I solve that?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-ch {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.second-ch {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  .square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
  }
.third-ch {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-ch"></div>
  <div class="second-ch">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-ch"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/mmroz5ks/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is old but for anyone reading this:

Using `align-self: stretch;` on the child element will also work :)

So in this case:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

...

.second-ch {
  max-width: 200px;
  align-self: stretch;
  ...
}

...
```

Answer (score 22):

Citing the comment of Jason Deppen:

> I solved it by also setting width: 100% along with my max-width value.

```
max-width: <your max width>;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 8):

Why is this happening ?

It's not really the effect of align-items: center. It's the omision of the default value, align-items: stretch , that makes the child grow.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;   /* default */
}

.first-ch {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.second-ch {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  .square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
  }
.third-ch {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-ch"></div>
  <div class="second-ch">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-ch"></div>
</div>
```

If you want the child to grow until it reaches the width-max, do as bolverin says and set the width explicitly

Answer (score 2):

why do you use `max-width: 200px;`? try `width: 200px;`
when you use `align-items : center` the `.second-ch` has minimal needed width.
`max-width` limits max width of the block but doesn't set minimal width

Comment: My issue was that I wanted a responsive box so I didn't want to set a fixed width. I solved it by also setting width: 100% along with my max-width value.